# javascript variables not setting - checked via firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, variables

I'm new to stackoverflow!

I'm having problems with a piece of code for my companies website, using jquery. I'm trying to track the clicks on two button and set a variable/s which can then be used to determine a course of action. Basically its a sliding dropdown that animates one way if the variable is set to true and another if it is set to false. I've initiallised the variables both to be false to begin with and then through the course of clicking they should be set to true or false depending on the situation:

```
var boollogin = false;
var boolregister = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#slidedownlogin').hide();
   $('#details_add_area').hide();
   $('#emailconfirmation').hide();
   $('#register').toggle(function(){
      if(boollogin == false){
         $('#login_area').hide();
         $('#register_area').show();
         $('#details_add_area').hide();
         $('#slidedownlogin').animate({'height':'235px'},1500, 'easeOutExpo');
      }else{
         $('#slidedownlogin').animate({'height':'0px'},1500, 'easeOutExpo',function(){
            $('#login_area').hide();
            $('#details_add_area').hide();
            $('#register_area').show();
            $('#slidedownlogin').animate({'height':'235px'},1500, 'easeOutExpo');
          });
      }
      boolregister = true;
   } , function(){
     $('#slidedownlogin').animate({'height':'0px'},1500, 'easeOutExpo', function(){
            $('#slidedownlogin').children().hide();
       });
       boolregister = false;
       boollogin = false;
    });

    $('#login').toggle(function(){
       if(boolregister == false){
          $('#register_area').hide();
          $('#details_add_area').hide();
          $('#login_area').show();
          $('#slidedownlogin').animate({'height':'220px'},1500, 'easeOutExpo');
       }else{  
          $('#slidedownlogin').animate({'height':'0px'},1500, 'easeOutExpo',function(){
             $('#register_area').hide();
             $('#details_add_area').hide();
             $('#login_area').show();
             $('#slidedownlogin').animate({'height':'220px'},1500, 'easeOutExpo');
           });
       }
       boollogin = true;
    } , function(){
         $('#slidedownlogin').animate({'height':'0px'},1500, 'easeOutExpo', function(){
            $('#slidedownlogin').children().hide();
         });
         boollogin = false;
         boolregister= false;
    });
});
```

The page I'm working on is at http://www.premiersoftware.co.uk/index94.php. Full code is in the php file at the moment so you can look at it there too. You should be able to get an idea of what I'm trying to do by clicking the two links (Register and Login) at the top right of the page.These are supposed to reset the variables boollogin or boolregister, but inspecting these two variables in firebug reveals they aren't being reset and don't change. As a result the page initially acts as expected but after a while and a few clicks it gets really quirky. The form valitation and stuff hasn't been done yet as I'm trying to get the animation sorted first.

I was hoping someone here would be able to shed some light on why the variables aren't being reset and suggest how I could fix the code. If there is another way to create the same kind of functionality I'm also open to suggestion.

Thanks in advance

Dan

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO)!!!

Comment: I don't know what it is you're doing with Firebug, but those variables are definitely changing. The page doesn't work very well however; if you click before the animation finishes, it gets confused.

Comment: I swear I set both variables to be ones to watch in firebug and after a few clicks neither had been re set.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of closing the div that drops down and then opening it up again when the user switches between login and register, it may be more intuitive to just display the correct register or login form within the opened div.

This code may help you regardless, but it implements what I suggested above.

http://jsbin.com/etezo5

edit link so you can see the code:

http://jsbin.com/etezo5/edit

Comment: This is probably a more elegant solution but I'm trying to emulate some previous software we produced. I've heard of using Queue and Stop() in Jquery to fine tune the animation but not sure how to apply them in this situation and whether it would be applicable. I used firebug and set the too variables boolregister and boollogin to be ones to watch and I swear they didn't change. Its fine to begin with switching from login (while open) to register seems to work, its just after that it gets all messed up.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest you check when you're setting the variables. You might have to set them inside the onComplete handlers for them to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing something like:

```
$('<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="register" onclick="toggleTheCorrectDiv(true)">Register</a>').appendTo('#support').css({'float':'right','margin-right':'10px'});
$('<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="login" onclick="toggleTheCorrectDiv(false)">Login</a>').appendTo('#support').css({'float':'right','margin-right':'10px'});
```

Then in your JS,

```
function toggleTheCorrectDiv(toggleRegister){
    if (toggleRegister){
       //Show Register Content
    }else{
       //Show Login Content
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems more like voodoo programming than a reasoned answer. Why is muddying up your HTML and JS the correct answer?

Comment: That's news to me - using an onclick event is considered "voodoo" or "muddying up" the HTML. This is pretty simple. In addition, I never claimed this as "THE" correct answer, but I certainly think that if the OP is having JS problems, this is a straight-forward way of doing the same thing. As in many cases, there is going to be more than one 'correct' answer for this. I might ask you, why write complicated javascript with multiple bool values when you can do something simple like this? I mean, we're talking about a basic event that triggers a function.

Comment: Wow! sorry,I didn't mean to start a debate of Voodoo proportions!:)  Seriously though I'm not sure how to do this, but theres multiple animations with the div sliding up before sliding down with new content, This could be an open div, a closed div with different content considering which button is pressed and as its a toggle I need the div to slide up and down with the press of the same button. The answer above seems too simplistic, either that or the answer is staring me right in the face and your right... I jsut cant see how to apply it right! :)